# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, spring-boot

No encuentro el fallo a ver si me podeis ayudar. El error es

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.proyecto.modelos.JuegosRol.usuario in com.proyecto.modelos.Usuario.listaJuegos
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:848) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:799) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

Tengo

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable, Logable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Size(max = 12)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "dni_usuario")
    private String dniUsuario;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "edad")
    private int edad;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usuario")
    private List<JuegosRol> listaJuegos;
```

y la otra

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "juegosrol")
public class JuegosRol implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    @Id
    @Size(max = 12)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_juego")
    private int idJuego;
    @JoinColumn(name = "dni_usuario", referencedColumnName = "dni_usuario")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Usuario idUsuario;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre_juego")
    private String nombreJuego;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "multiJugdor")
    private boolean multiJugdor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `mappedBy` hace referencia al nombre del atributo de la clase. En tu clase el nombre del atributo es `idUsuario` por lo que debería ser `mappedBy = "idUsuario"`